# Servers must be able to freely connect to the rest of the Internet, so they must not set UseBridges

Tags: configuration

trying to configure bridges, but I'm getting error:

`Servers must be able to freely connect to the rest of the Internet, so they must not set  UseBridges`

my config in `/etc/tor/torrc`

````
User tor

SOCKSPort 9050
ORPort 9001

MaxCircuitDirtiness 10
CircuitBuildTimeout 10
ExcludeExitNodes {US}
StrictNodes 1

# BridgeRelay 1
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:9001
ORPort 9001
ExtORPort auto


UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy


Bridge obfs4 94.142.246.132:8088 135C158527AA9FE9A2F26EC515EB6999D813D347 cert=wTUz0/5FhAZRkitil5MprGbSF3JzjxjxI1kAmxAdSeDy98NgcLr11f/qUXWDC76Y97RiSg iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 172.104.232.194:8083 5E2D18551CE8ADC540DDAD1178771ED7AD265D8F cert=30PZIXba0B5tPC1c27SVWxclrSOR9SNvDIi+mk2a+zccwvaEcKvQkEi+tf/06D2LoNX7cQ iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 20.102.79.78:22022 B5705F7E616DAB0F477E3E1ADC23E40413F683FE cert=1Cc/hwPtPjzFKGHVOP0j/qmBgnvquRx8+im35/u5TIYjDQ3FlMfA5VvTrQ/hbX8BZZooLQ iat-mode=0```
````

Comment: What's the goal of your configuration here? Are you trying to run a tor relay? Are you trying to act as a bridge, or trying to use other bridges? You're currently trying to run a tor relay while using bridges, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Steve I want to use tor to proxify requests, but in my country tor blocked, then I decided to setup Bridges. 
as I understand Bridges can help me to get around internet provider blocks and then I would can proxify my requests by socks5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file is trying to run a tor relay, not just a client.

You need to remove the following lines:

```
ORPort 9001

# BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:9001
ORPort 9001
ExtORPort auto
```

Comment: works! thanks a lot